# What is the best way to cut railway sleepers

Tags: saw, cutting, chainsaw, circular-saw

Is it possible? Is the wood treatment of the sleepers affecting my equipment
Tools in my possession: electric chainsaw, circular saw and an handsaw.

Comment: I've always seen guys use chainsaws, but they don't use their good chain. They either use an old chain, or get ride of the chain when they're done.

Comment: Dynamite. What are you doing? Trying to start a guerilla war?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about railroad ties, just buy a cheap circular saw blade for about $5, use it for the railroad ties and then throw away. It won't go all the way through, even if using on all four sides, but will get close. You can then finish with a bow saw or just strike it against something to split it the rest of the way.